# Data on view is not binding with controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newbie AngularJS. I'm trying to make a checkbox with following properties.
    1.selects and deselects all other checkbox coresponding to the **All** checkbox

2.if all **otherCheckbox**  are selected then **All** checkbox is automatically selected.if one of the **otherCheckbox** is unselected then **All** checkbox is automatically unselected.  
 Here is the code in view

```
<div ng-repeat="fence in thisUserFence">
  <label>                                                              
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fence.status" ng-change="otherCheckbox()">{{fence.name}}                                  
  </label>{{fence.status}}
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkAll()" ng-model="isAllSelected">All                                                
  </label>{{isAllSelected}}
</div>
```

Code in controller-

```
$scope.checkAll=function(){
  var checkStatus=!$scope.isAllSelected;
  $scope.isAllSelected=!$scope.isAllSelected;
  console.log($scope.isAllSelected);
  angular.forEach($scope.thisUserFence,function(fence){fence.status=checkStatus;});
}
$scope.otherCheckbox=function(){
  $scope.isAllSelected=$scope.thisUserFence.every(function(item){return item.status;});
  console.log($scope.isAllSelected);
}
```

Above logic works fine untill you check **All** checkbox and then unselect 
any of **otherCheckbox** .
The value of **$scope.isAllSelected** is **false** in console but in view value of **{{isAllSelected}}** is **true** .Its not updating in view.

Comment: your code is working fine, whats the issue

Comment: see link https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/7416/

Comment: When i select ALL checkbox then all other checkbox are also get selected but then if i unselect one of the other checkbox then ALL checkbox doesn't  change to unselect.  if i print value of  $scope.isAllSelected in console it show's false but in view same isAllselected show's true.

Comment: click on add .... its not working

Comment: what do you mean by click on add its not working

Comment: where is 'add' in your question

Comment: by mistaken i have typed add but actually it is all

Comment: in the jsfiddle example when i click All it select all other check boxes and when again pressing deselect all other check boxes

Comment: check again when you click on all nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Just change checkAll method like this, you do not need to change the status of isAllSelected in the method cause its already binded to the check box model

```
    $scope.checkAll=function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.thisUserFence,function(fence) {
                fence.status=$scope.isAllSelected;
                });
          }
```

See working example here https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/7426/

Comment: yes we can do like this but actually checkboxes are on modal and i want to update value in modal through controller . so here problem arises

Comment: please update your question and add a working example so that i can come to know what is the problem you are facing